# How to get rid of these code highlighters in WebStorm?

Tags: ide, webstorm, highlight

How to get rid of the code highlighting on `oi-options`, `ng-model` etc.

[image: Look at this image]

I'm not sure what's the name of this option.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the option is. It's "Unknown HTML tag". I think they've been highlighted due to the fact my HTML code has AngularJS functions in it. You can turn it off by going to

**Settings > Editor > Inspections > HTML > Unknown HTML tag**

Comment: WebStorm should normally be able to resolve custom AngularJS directives. From your screenshot it seems that even standard Angular directives like `ng-model` are marked as unknown... Do you have `angular.js` file in your project? It is required for enabling AngularJS support

Comment: I do, however I only open certain folder of my application in Webstorm as there are simply too many folders. It is easier for me to navigate with just a few folders. angular.js file sits higher in the directory hierarchy and is not 'found' I guess.

Comment: *"It is easier for me to navigate with just a few folders."* Use Scopes for that -- they can be used in Project View as well.